# Kafka - What does it mean by cluster-wide

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I had 3 broker kafka setup. I am in the process of updating "min.insync.replicas" property, and I looked at the documentation,

> min.insync.replicas
>
> Update Mode:  cluster-wide

1. What does "cluster-wide" specify here - Is it ok if i update the property in one broker or is it required to be updated in all broker settings file ( server.properties)
2. How to update "cluster-wide" property using kafka-config -

> All configs that are configurable at cluster level may also be
> configured at per-broker level (e.g. for testing). If a config value
> is defined at different levels, the following order of precedence is
> used: Dynamic per-broker config stored in ZooKeeper Dynamic
> cluster-wide default config stored in ZooKeeper Static broker config
> from server.properties Kafka default, see broker configs
>
> From Kafka version 1.1 onwards, some of the broker configs can be
> updated without restarting the broker. See the Dynamic Update Mode
> column in Broker Configs for the update mode of each broker config.
> read-only: Requires a broker restart for update per-broker: May be
> updated dynamically for each broker cluster-wide: May be updated
> dynamically as a cluster-wide default. May also be updated as a
> per-broker value for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[min.insync.replicas](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html#min.insync.replicas) means the no. of replicas of a topic partition that needs to be in sync.

> What does "cluster-wide" specify here - Is it ok if i update the
>   property in one broker or is it required to be updated in all broker
>   settings file ( server.properties)

A cluster-wide configuration is that which should apply for all brokers. So updating once should reflect for other brokers, otherwise there could be no difference between *cluster-wide* config and *per-broker* config.

---

The configuration *min.insync.replicas* is configurable at both topic level as well as cluster level.

When we set it at topic level, it applies only to that topic, no matter in what brokers the topic partitions are.

When we set it at broker level, it will be default for all topics, unless otherwise specified.

---

> How to update "cluster-wide" property using kafka-config?

The config entity type here will be `topics` if you want to set to a topic.

If you want to set it at broker level, then it is `brokers`

---

Here is the full list (as of 2.3.1)

```
--add-config <String>                  Key Value pairs of configs to add.     
                                         Square brackets can be used to group 
                                         values which contain commas: 'k1=v1, 
                                         k2=[v1,v2,v2],k3=v3'. The following  
                                         is a list of valid configurations:   
                                         For entity-type 'topics':            
                                        cleanup.policy                        
                                        compression.type                      
                                        confluent.tier.enable                 
                                        confluent.tier.local.hotset.bytes     
                                        confluent.tier.local.hotset.ms        
                                        delete.retention.ms                   
                                        file.delete.delay.ms                  
                                        flush.messages                        
                                        flush.ms                              
                                        follower.replication.throttled.       
                                         replicas                             
                                        index.interval.bytes                  
                                        leader.replication.throttled.replicas 
                                        max.compaction.lag.ms                 
                                        max.message.bytes                     
                                        message.downconversion.enable         
                                        message.format.version                
                                        message.timestamp.difference.max.ms   
                                        message.timestamp.type                
                                        min.cleanable.dirty.ratio             
                                        min.compaction.lag.ms                 
                                        min.insync.replicas                   
                                        preallocate                           
                                        retention.bytes                       
                                        retention.ms                          
                                        segment.bytes                         
                                        segment.index.bytes                   
                                        segment.jitter.ms                     
                                        segment.ms                            
                                        unclean.leader.election.enable        
                                       For entity-type 'brokers':             
                                        log.message.timestamp.type            
                                        ssl.client.auth                       
                                        log.retention.ms                      
                                        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter      
                                        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.    
                                         factor                               
                                        log.preallocate                       
                                        log.index.size.max.bytes              
                                        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor      
                                        ssl.truststore.type                   
                                        ssl.keymanager.algorithm              
                                        log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor     
                                        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds 
                                        ssl.key.password                      
                                        background.threads                    
                                        log.retention.bytes                   
                                        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm            
                                        log.segment.bytes                     
                                        max.connections.per.ip.overrides      
                                        log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms       
                                        log.segment.delete.delay.ms           
                                        min.insync.replicas                   
                                        ssl.keystore.location                 
                                        ssl.cipher.suites                     
                                        log.roll.jitter.ms                    
                                        log.cleaner.backoff.ms                
                                        sasl.jaas.config                      
                                        principal.builder.class               
                                        log.flush.interval.ms                 
                                        confluent.tier.enable                 
                                        log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms     
                                        max.connections                       
                                        log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size        
                                        log.flush.interval.messages           
                                        advertised.listeners                  
                                        num.io.threads                        
                                        listener.security.protocol.map        
                                        log.message.downconversion.enable     
                                        sasl.enabled.mechanisms               
                                        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds     
                                        ssl.truststore.password               
                                        listeners                             
                                        metric.reporters                      
                                        ssl.protocol                          
                                        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter     
                                        ssl.keystore.password                 
                                        sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol  
                                        log.cleanup.policy                    
                                        sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules
                                        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin 
                                        num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir     
                                        log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second   
                                        log.roll.ms                           
                                        confluent.tier.local.hotset.ms        
                                        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm 
                                        unclean.leader.election.enable        
                                        message.max.bytes                     
                                        log.cleaner.threads                   
                                        log.cleaner.io.buffer.size            
                                        max.connections.per.ip                
                                        sasl.kerberos.service.name            
                                        ssl.provider                          
                                        follower.replication.throttled.rate   
                                        log.index.interval.bytes              
                                        log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms     
                                        log.message.timestamp.difference.max. 
                                         ms                                   
                                        ssl.enabled.protocols                 
                                        confluent.tier.local.hotset.bytes     
                                        log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio       
                                        replica.alter.log.dirs.io.max.bytes.  
                                         per.second                           
                                        ssl.keystore.type                     
                                        ssl.secure.random.implementation      
                                        ssl.truststore.location               
                                        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd               
                                        leader.replication.throttled.rate     
                                        num.network.threads                   
                                        compression.type                      
                                        num.replica.fetchers                  
                                       For entity-type 'users':               
                                        request_percentage                    
                                        producer_byte_rate                    
                                        SCRAM-SHA-256                         
                                        SCRAM-SHA-512                         
                                        consumer_byte_rate                    
                                       For entity-type 'clients':             
                                        request_percentage                    
                                        producer_byte_rate                    
                                        consumer_byte_rate                    
                                       Entity types 'users' and 'clients' may 
                                         be specified together to update      
                                         config for clients of a specific     
                                         user.
```

Dynamic cluster-wide default config stored in ZooKeeper ([Reference](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/dynamic-config.html)) so it applies to all brokers.

Comment: I doubt it is not  topic level configuration when you refer it as topic level configuration. As per documentation, is is mentioned under broker configurations.

Comment: You can see the link in the answer

Comment: where does it mention it is topic level configuration

Comment: The very fact that it is listed in a page titled *Topic configurations*, itself says that.

Comment: What you say as broker level configuration, could be default for all topics

Comment: hmm, i see it is listed under broker configs here - https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#min.insync.replicas

Comment: Yes, that is default for all topics if not specified.

Comment: Yes, it should be applied to all brokers, because for other properties like `advertised.listeners` it is not cluster wide, meaning it is per-broker since each broker can specify its own

Comment: what happens if it is NOT specified in all the brokers ?

Comment: Other brokers could take it from the zookeeper, I guess. Because it is cluster-wide and zookeeper holds the metadata.

Comment: u mean, if configuration file of one broker is updated with a change, it will be stored in zookeeper and other brokers will borrow the value from it since it is latest value ? do you have an article that confirms this point

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/dynamic-config.html - first section, last points.